# Can Aegis take the Open Minded feat?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, psionics

The [Open Minded](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/feats/open-minded/) feat (*Psionics Unleashed*) says:

> You are naturally able to reroute your memory, mind, and skill expertise.
>
> **Benefit:** You gain 1 skill point for every Hit Die you possess. You gain 1 skill point whenever you gain a Hit Die (such as when you gain a level). You spend these skill points as normal. You cannot exceed the normal maximum point for your level in any skill.

Can an Elan Aegis access this feat? If so, does that mean that a level 12 Elan aegis with 130 hit die gains 130 skill points?

And what happens if they are a multiclassed level 10 human 2hweapon fighter + level 2 Elan aegis?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any prerequisites for the feat. Is there a reason you think they couldn't take it?

Comment: alemayo - If you feel that one answer satisfies your question, then you can [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/) that answer by clicking the "check mark" button next to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though Open Minded was printed in *Psionics Unleashed*, it isn’t a psionic feat—it’s just a general feat. And it has no prerequisites. So yes, an elan aegis can take it—literally anyone ever can take it (unless they already have).

However, you do not have 130 hit dice—you have 130 hit **points**. Each time you level up, you get **one** hit die, and then you roll that die and add your Constitution to determine how many hit points you have. So your hit dice (HD) are equal to your level—and Pathfinder doesn’t go past 20th level. Open Minded, effectively, gives you one extra skill point per *level*. It doesn’t matter what those levels are in, so a 10th-level fighter/2nd-level aegis is just the same as any other 12th-level character for Open Minded: you get 12 skill points.

Answer (score 1):

The Open Minded feat has no prerequisites. You can just take it, one time, when you get an opportunity to take it (such as by gaining your 13th character level, or retraining an old feat to replace it with a new one using the rules presented in *Pathfinder Roleplaying Game Ultimate Campaign* or introduced by your GM). When you do so, you gain skill points equal to your number of Hit Dice (usually class levels plus racial Hit Dice, which an elan shouldn't have), in your case about 12 or 13 (whichever is your character level at the time), to spend instantly.

Every time you gain a Hit Die after that, you gain 1 more skill point than you normally would; for aegis levels, this would mean 4 + your Intelligence modifier + 1. For fighter levels, it would be 2 + your Intelligence modifier + 1. (If aegis or fighter was your favored class, you could choose to gain yet another skill point each time you took a level of your favored class, as normal: see page 31 of the *Pathfinder Roleplaying Game Core Rulebook*, "Favored Class".)

So, if you retrain to gain Open Minded, you should have 40 skill points (20 from your fighter levels, 8 from your aegis levels, and 12 from Open Minded) + 12 times your Intelligence modifier. Plus however many times you chose to gain a skill point from your favored class bonus (anywhere from 0 to 10 if you created a character with fighter as your favored class).

Comment: Yes KRyan, Sorry, I made a mistake, now I understand. Both answers are clear and complete, thank you.